# Microsoft T/SQL, Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Sorting based on Year and then Month. I have one Column Period.

It has contins dates from **Jan-2016** up to **APR-2018**.

I want to Sort based on Recent Year then Month also needs to be sorted.

Result should look like:

- Jan-2018
- Feb-2018
- Mar-2018
- Apr-2018
- Jan-2017
- Feb-2017 up to Dec-2017
- then for 2016: Jan-2016
- Feb-2016
- Mar-2016 up to Dec-2016

I did something like this, but it has an issue:

```
Cast(Year(cast(Q.Column Name as small date time)) as char(4)) + '-' + CASE WHEN Month(cast (Q.Column Name as small date time)) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END  + cast(Month(cast (Q.Column Name as small date time)) as char(2))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why are some months randomly grouped? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Format properly!!!  No one is going to read code in one long line without formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply `ORDER BY` that separately orders against year and month using `CAST` and `DATEPART`:

```
declare @tmp table ([period] varchar(10))
insert into @tmp values 
('Jan-2016'), ('Feb-2016'), ('Mar-2016'), ('Apr-2016'), ('May-2016'), ('Jun-2016'), ('Jul-2016'), ('Aug-2016'), ('Sep-2016'), ('Oct-2016'), ('Nov-2016'), ('Dec-2016'), ('Jan-2017'), ('Feb-2017'), ('Mar-2017'), ('Apr-2017'), ('May-2017'), ('Jun-2017'), ('Jul-2017'), ('Aug-2017'), ('Sep-2017'), ('Oct-2017'), ('Nov-2017'), ('Dec-2017'), ('Jan-2018'), ('Feb-2018'), ('Mar-2018'), ('Apr-2018')

select  *
from @tmp 
order by DATEPART(year, cast( '1-' +  [period] as date)) desc, 
         DATEPART(month,cast( '1-' +  [period] as date)) asc
```

On the left side the original order, on the right side the results after the `order by`:

[image]

In your case:

```
select  *
from YOUR_TABLE_NAME 
order by DATEPART(year, cast( '1-' +  [period] as date)) desc, 
         DATEPART(month,cast( '1-' +  [period] as date)) asc
```

Comment: @Andrea..Thank you for your response but I it has to be dynamic. I have one table with Period Column. It should come from this table.

Comment: Then you should post sample data, @John.  For details, see [mcve]

Comment: @John Yes, I know that it must be dynamic: to give a complete solution I declared a table variable with static values to show that it works. To make it dynamic just remove the first three lines of the script and replace `@tmp` with the name of your table

Comment: @Andrea, I'm using a view and can not use Order by clause. This is what I'm trying.   Cast(Year(cast(Period as smalldatetime)) as char(4)) + '-' + CASE WHEN Month(cast (Period as smalldatetime)) < 10 THEN '0' ELSE '' END  + cast(Month(cast (Period as smalldatetime)) as char(2)) MonthSort

Comment: @John Please add all required details to your question, otherwise it is impossible to help you. You shoul add that you are using a view, the TSQL code for you view, sample data from your tables/views and desired output